# How do I wire this AC motor to a UK plug?

Tags: motor, ac, mains, wiring, grounding

[image]When wiring this 220V, 60rpm AC motor to the mains, it turns perfectly with the live and neutral wires connected to terminals 1 and 2 and with the earth wire disconnected from terminal 3, however it does not turn when the earth wire is connected to terminal 3. The seller indicates that the live and neutral wires are to be connected to these terminals, but does not mention the earth wire, or the purpose of the third terminal. How do I resolve this when wiring it to UK mains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to terminals 1 and 2 (or 3) as instructed by the product documentation. Carefully connect an earth wire to the motor housing with one of the screws that attach the terminal block to the housing. You could also connect the earth wire using one of the holes in the housing used to mount the motor. If you do that, remove the paint where contact is made.

Answer (score 0):

It's a split phase AC induction motor with start/run-capacitor (phase shifter) and that third terminal is for the capacitor and NOT earth.

> How do I resolve this when wiring it to UK mains?

What does the product documentation tell you about using it and wiring it up? Is it CE marked?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm afraid I'm quite new to using motors. It is not CE marked. The product documentation only says to directly connect in a line of 220V power supply to terminal 2 and another line to terminal 1 (or to 3 to reverse direction). Is there another way to safely connect to mains?

Comment: The product documentation is correct. The run-capacitor is already connected to the terminal, it's the brown piece. When you connect terminals 1+2 to mains, terminal 3 is connected through the run-cap and the motor runs forward, when you connect terminals 2+3 to mains, terminal 1 is connected through the run-cap and the motor runs backward. The earth wire does not go anywhere at that terminal but to one of the mounting screws instead.

Comment: @cassia if the motor case is plastic there is a good chance you don't need an earth but, because safety is involved you must follow guidelines given by the seller or manufacturer. However, I would play safe and ensure the circuit that feeds the motor has a residual current detect device. Play safely.